# Convergence of $\,\log^\tau (n+1) - \log^\tau n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm having trouble in proving convergence of:

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (\log^\tau{(n+1)} - \log^\tau{n}) \to 0$

for any $\tau \in \mathbb{R}: \tau>0$.

Comment: Hint: Use monotone convergence theorem for sequence.

Comment: The theorem doesn't help to evaluate the limit exactly. It just says that it converges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem,

$$\tag 1\log^\tau (n+1) - \log^\tau n = \tau(\log c_n)^{\tau-1}\cdot \frac{1}{c_n}\cdot 1$$

for some $c_n \in (n,n+1).$ Now use the fact that for any $p\in \mathbb R,$

$$\lim_{u\to \infty} \frac{\log^p u}{u} =0.$$

Thus the limit of $(1)$ is $0.$

Comment: So, probably this solution can be expanded for a function: $x^\sigma\log^\tau (x+1): 0<\sigma<1$ 

$n^\sigma(\log^\tau (n+1) - \log^\tau n) = \frac{\sigma\log^{\tau}c_n + \tau\log^{\tau-1}c_n}{c_n^{1-\sigma}}$.